# -Roblox- Some sort of camera glitch when switching between player and part

Tags: roblox

Currently i'm making a game in which you hit "L" on the keyboard and it changes to the part that you can control...
But the weird thing is that when it approaches a player(Not the player who spawned it...),it freezes. But on the other player's screen it is still able to move about.

I used a local script in the player's Backpack for cam change...
when I switch to (cam.CameraSubject = part.Humanoid), it does the glitch/bug I describe,including all the other parts inside the model. But if I have
(cam.CameraSubject = part(The model)),it works but it's laggy...
Any other ways I can go about doing this???
Is it possible the part that i'm using is too small???

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is due to how ROBLOX simulates physics. When a part is physically simulated, the actual work of simulating the part is delegated to the closest client. This distance is based on where the player's character is in the game world. If no player is close, the server itself takes on the duty of simulating the part.

Therefore, if you have a part a player is controlling, the part might actually be *physically* controlled by another player's computer if it is closer. That is probably why your part seems to freeze up when it gets close to another player.

---

**The solution:** [SetNetworkOwner](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/BasePart/SetNetworkOwner)

A while back, ROBLOX added some helpful methods that allow game developers to override the default physics delegation that I described above. By using `BasePart:SetNetworkOwner(player)`, you can dictate what client should be responsible for handling the physics of the object.

So all you need to do is get a server-side script to call `SetNetworkOwner` on that control part you mentioned:

```
controlPart:SetNetworkOwner(player)
```

Here's a little example. When the player enters, a part is created and assigned to the player. Note how `SetNetworkOwner` is used. When the player leaves, the part is destroyed:

```
local controlPart = Instance.new("Part")
local controlParts = {}

function PlayerAdded(player)
    local part = controlPart:Clone()
    part.Parent = game.Workspace
    controlParts[player] = part

    -- Set the network owner to the player:
    part:SetNetworkOwner(player)

end

function PlayerRemoving(player)
    local part = controlParts[player]
    if (part) then
        part:Destroy()
    end
    controlParts[player] = nil
end

game.Players.PlayerAdded:connect(PlayerAdded)
game.Players.PlayerRemoving:connect(PlayerRemoving)
```

Note:

- You cannot set the network owner of an Anchored part
- If you set the network owner of a part that is connected to other unanchored parts, those parts will also inherit the network owner change

Please refer to the official ROBLOX Wiki page on [Network Ownership](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Network_ownership) for further information on this topic.